# How to display an image which comes back from an axios request (React)?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, axios

I'm working on a google maps project with React. I assign an onClick handler the following method:

```
  getStreetView(lat,lng){
    let url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=${lat},${lng}&heading=151.78&pitch=-0.76&key=MYAPIKEY`
    axios.get(url).then(response=>this.setState({image:response.config.url}));
  }
```

the `state = { image: null }` is then beeing assigned the url which I later pass on to an image tag to a child component such as `<img src={props.image} alt='street view'/>`. Everything works like a charm, however I have come across various other solutions such:

```
function getBase64(url) {
  return axios
    .get(url, {
      responseType: 'arraybuffer'
    })
    .then(response => Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64'))
}
```

from `b4dnewz` from the axios documentation. However I can't find a reasonable approach how to display the image in child component with that response type. My question is, is my approach valid? Is there any reasons why I shouldn't be using it like that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are getting the image url from api, then your first method is the right approach, but the

```
Buffer.from(response.data, 'binary').toString('base64'))
```

method is used when the image itself is received from server as a binary which is converted to base 64 and given to `<img>`