# Display my image from MS Graph to Azure Bot Services

Tags: node.js, azure-active-directory, botframework, microsoft-graph-api, azure-bot-service

How can I send the user a card with a photo I received from Microsoft Graph, like from the url `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value`? I think it returns a blob but the bot framework wants an image url instead. I tried it with `CardFactory.heroCard(..., [photo], ...)` but it didn't show it.

Comment: Are you using the Node BotBuilder SDK v4?

Comment: Yes @KyleDelaney

Comment: Is your goal to show the user their own profile photo?

Comment: No. It's to show anyone's photo. I used /me just because it's easier than finding a specific user's id. `me` is easier. I don't know what this question has to do with my issue.

Comment: Is there a particular tutorial you used to help you authenticate the Microsoft Graph API?

Comment: Yes. [This one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service#authentication-and-authorization-steps) for getting access to Microsoft Graph and [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0) for getting the picture.

Comment: What channel are you using? There is a way to embed photos in messages, but it depends on channel capabilities. If a channel doesn't support embedded images, you'd have to upload the photo to a public URL and it might not be a good idea to expose someone's personal data like that.

Comment: I'm using the web channel. It accepts images, but only an image URL. Not the blob of an image.

Comment: Do you mean Web Chat?

Comment: Is my answer acceptable?

Comment: It might not be until a while until I can test it (We're working on a different project.) I'll assume it works and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#add-a-media-attachment) describes how to include an inline image binary in a message:

> For channels that support inline binaries of an image, you can set the `contentUrl` property of the `Attachment` to a base64 binary of the image (for example, data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo…). The channel will display the image or the image's URL next to the message's text string.

In the BotBuilder V4 Node SDK, you can convert the image binary to base64 like this:

```
// After getting an HTTP response:

var imageType = "image/jpeg"
var imageBytes = Buffer.from(response.data).toString('base64');
var imageSrc = `data:${imageType};base64,${imageBytes}`;

var reply = MessageFactory.attachment({
    contentType: imageType,
    contentUrl: imageSrc,
    name: "Your photo"
}, "Here it is:");

await turnContext.sendActivity(reply);
```

There is one gotcha to keep in mind. If you're using the Axios library (which is a good idea because it lets you await HTTP requests), [you will need to set the `responseType` in the config to `arrayBuffer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50772724/how-to-display-an-image-which-comes-back-from-an-axios-request-react) or else the image binary may be formatted incorrectly and the image won't render:

```
var response = await axios.get("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/photo/$value", {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
});
```